# why I can not find the correct derivative with D

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

the coupled ODE is

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{(x[r] (192 + (20 r^3 y''[r])/y[r]))/
r^4 == 5 x''[r]/r, 
1000 (2 (x'[r])^2 + 2 x[r] x''[r]) + 
  250 (2 (y'[r])^2 + 2 y[r] y''[r]) == -5/(4 r), 
x[1] == 0, 
y[1] == 1/10 Sqrt[1/2 Log[5/2]], 
y'[1] == -((1 - Log[5/2])/(20 Sqrt[2 Log[5/2]])), 
x'[1] == a, 
WhenEvent[y[r] < 10^(-6), end = r; "StopIntegration", 
 "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]},
 {x, y}, {r, 1, 5/2}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}];
```

I want to plot this expression:

```
g[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Evaluate[{(Pi (256 x[r]^2 + 16 y[r]^2))/(2 r^3) + 
   5/2 Pi ((x'[r])^2 + (y'[r])^2)} /. 
 f[a]], {r, 1, end}][[1, 1]]
```

the plot of `g[a]` with respect to `a` in the region `{a, 0.0026, 0.008}`
[image]

there is a minimum there, so I use `D` the find the derivative at `a=0.0028`

```
D[g[a], a] /. a -> 0.0028
 0.0500445
```

the result is rather surprising, since the figure show the slope at `a=0.0028` should be negative. what's wrong with `D`?

thanks a lot

one more fact, `findminimum` and `NMinimize` give me the correct answer of `a` where the slope is `0`

Comment: Have you looked at all the error/warning messages being printed? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ESouu.png) it is best to take care of all these first before.

Comment: @Nasser, I set workingprecision by default, the problem still exsits.

Comment: If you are looking for a minimum, why are you plugging in a=0.0028? That minimum seems to occur past 0.004. I've punched in the following:

    Manipulate[
    Plot[
    Evaluate[ReplaceAll[{x[r], y[r]}, f[a]]],
    {r, 0.9, 2.6}, PlotRange -> {-0.02, 0.07}],
    {a, 0.0026, 0.008}]

I also changed the NDSolve bounds to give me some wiggle room with the r values (notice I'm plotting just outside the range {1,2.5}. This seems to indicate that solutions go haywire at or right around 2.5 when a<0.333. Finding g[a] for those values (and D[g[a],a]) will be dodgy.

Comment: See also: Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  Table[{a, g[a]}, {a, 0.0026, 0.004, da}],
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.1, 0.3}
  ], {da, {0.0005, 0.0002, 0.0001, 0.00005, 0.00002, 0.00001}}
 ]

Comment: You're forcing the system to approximate the derivative numerically.  `Derivative` can indeed do this, but I've found it to be not so reliable in some cases.  Try the `ND` function instead from the NumericalCalculus package.  It gives `-15.1987`.  I do not know how accurate this is and how much it's influenced by the precision used in the implementation of `g`.  I think the precision of that NIntegrate and NDSolve may have a significant effect over this.

Comment: @KellenMyers, I need to find the minimum, the first code comes to me is `D`. now I can just use `findminimum` instead. thanks a lot

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for your notice. I almost forget I should have used `ND`. I am just curious why `D` fails in this case

Comment: @3c. I don't know, but if I try to estimate the derviative manually using a naive first order approximation, I also run into trouble.  I wouldn't trust ND's result without verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will be a combination of some of the comments and then a few methods to try to find the value of $a$ you seem to want.

First of all, as I note, $a=0.0028$ is clearly not the minimum (nor near it). Now, that's not a problem, you should still be able to insist that the derivative $g'(0.0028)$ be computed correctly. You are fairly sure that this is wrong:

```
D[g[a], a] /. a -> 0.0028
out: 0.0500449
```

As Szabolcs points out, you should be using a numerical derivative:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
ND[g[a], a, 0.0028]
out: -15.1987
```

Now, it was your concern that $g'(0.0028)$ should be negative, however it's interesting that this is convincing enough when we can check and see:

```
a0 = 0.0028;
g0 = g[a0];
m = ND[g[a], a, a0];
Show[
 ListPlot[
  ParallelTable[{a, g[a]}, {a, 0.0026, 0.008, 0.00001}],
  Joined -> True
  ],
 Plot[m (a - a0) + g0, {a, a0 - 0.001, a0 + 0.001}]
 ]
```

[image: graph with tangent line]

The tangent line actually doesn't match -- it seems maybe to match the overall slope (a sort of average slope in a nearby interval of $a$ values, perhaps), but it's still not right.

The distraction here, which shouldn't be a problem, is the issue of some singularity or stiffness (which, I should note, you've set `"StiffnessTest" -> False`) at $a=0.0033$ or thereabouts. I mentioned above that you can see a "kink" in $g(a)$ just by plotting it:

[image: g(a) on a long interval]

[image: g(a) on a short interval]

And I noted that if you widen the NDSolve interval a bit and do some plotting, you can see that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, with the substitution $f(a)$, have a blowup at $t=5/2$ when $a<0.0033$.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[ReplaceAll[{x[r], y[r]}, f[a]]],
  {r, 0.9, 2.6}, PlotRange -> {-0.02, 0.07}],
 {a, 0.0026, 0.008}]
```

[image: plot with larger a, well behaved]

[image: plot with smaller a, poorly behaved]

Now, the `ND` command has already had issues above, so it's not advisable to use it, but we could try:

```
FindRoot[ND[g[a], a, b], {b, 0.004}]
output: {b -> -0.00477551}
```

That's not right, and it's not even close. I assume because the minimum is too close to this bad value of $a$ (and with a steep region between the two values of $a$). The `FindRoot` command won't be very useful here, I think.

You can try `NMinimize` but I'm not sure that's the right command -- it's not the type of command I'd normally use in this instance because it's meant to minimize a function over its entire domain. (Worse, this is an interpolated function, so beyond the interpolation bounds, who knows what happens.) You can try it constrained if you want:

```
NMinimize[{ND[g[a], a, b], 0.34 <= b <= 0.5}, b]
```

I couldn't even get this one to work. Maybe there's a better way to use `NMinimize` that I'm not seeing, but I `$Aborted` this one.

Here's what you should do:

```
FindMinimum[g[a], {a, 0.34, 0.5}]
out: {0.0841652, {a -> 0.00417839}}
```

This value of $a$ is confirmed visually by the plot of $g(a)$ you've already got.

You can test this out:

```
ND[g[a], a, 0.00417]
out: 2.21822
```

D'oh. That's wrong. Let's try to get some precision:

```
ND[g[a], a, 0.00417, Terms -> 30]
out: -0.0396302
```

We can even do a quick list to see:

```
ParallelTable[ND[g[a], a, a0], {a0, 0.0041, 0.0042, 0.00001}]
ParallelTable[ND[g[a], a, a0, Terms -> 30], {a0, 0.0041, 0.0042, 0.00001}]
```

I've omitted output, but the first list looks useless (values like 2.20574) while the second list works properly and gives relatively accurate numbers. The smallest values of `ND[g[a],a,a0]` occur near the value of $a$ we already found.

This also let's us try to reprise our attempt to use `FindRoot` as follows:

```
FindRoot[ND[g[a], a, b, Terms -> 30], {b, 0.00417}]
```

But even so, this takes more than 20 minutes to compute, which is longer than I'm willing to wait. There is a chance that using about 30 terms may give you accurate enough `ND`s that the FindRoot will work (but it might not).

You can use more `Terms` to examine various values of the derivative. You might notice something odd happen:

```
ParallelTable[ND[g[a], a, a0, Terms -> 30], {a0, 0.002, 0.008, 0.0001}]
out: {-46.8032, -43.3339, -38.4327, -18.6678, 5.38868, -11.5114,
      -33.1248, 30.2456, -83.6159, -47.3033, -0.866833, -5.92381, -87.673,
      -558.373, 20.4022, -29.6248, -11.608, -6.2123, -3.61962, -2.10121,
      -1.10858, -0.412773, 0.0988319, 0.48823, 0.792357, 1.03462, 1.23061,
      1.39109, 1.52376, 1.63425, 1.72682, 1.80469, 1.8704, 1.92594,
      1.97291, 2.0126, 2.04607, 2.07419, 2.09769, 2.11719, 2.1332, 2.14615,
      2.15644, 2.16437, 2.17023, 2.17425, 2.17666, 2.17763, 2.17732,
      2.17588, 2.17343, 2.17008, 2.16594, 2.16108, 2.15559, 2.14954,
      2.14299, 2.13598, 2.12859, 2.12084, 2.11278}
```

Notice that the first 10-15 values here are erratic. More `Terms` might yield some idea of whether these are "correct" in some sense (for example, fixing that tangent line we started with), but I think all this should really indicate that anything we do with values prior to $a=0.0033$ is probably incorrect or at least quite strange and at least dubious.

(Note: Don't use too many `Terms` or all the derivatives will blow up or vanish, I think due to issues with using too many terms in the Euler sums used by `ND` that go beyond the precision in the `NDSolve` and/or `NIntegrate` in the definitions of $f$ and $g$. There may be other options in `ND` that can be used to get more accurate output.)

But I hope this clears up the issues. In the end, the lesson seems to be: Use `FindMinimum` (and a bonus lesson: Steer clear of bad values of $a$).

Comment: thanks very much. in the end I think all such strange behaviors originate from the stiffness problem of the ODE. now I force the function to end before the stiffness comes out, then everything is well behaved